# Update MS Access connection string from 2003 to 2010

Tags: vb6

I have an old Visual basic application that is written by someone else. I have the following connection string defined in the code. For the following connection string, I was told that i need to install Office access 2003 on my computer and then only the code will work. Is there any way, I can upgrade the following string so instead of office access 2003, i will start using office access 2010.

```
 Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + gDBPath + ";Persist Security Info=False
```

I want to use office access 2010. Right now, I am running this code in windows XP, but i will soon migrate the code to windows 7

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it seems that  your connection is  for ACCESS 2007 ,2010 and  2013!

So  It doesn't seems to cause any issue  if you do  upgrade using  current string.
Look below

https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-access-accdb-odbc-driver/